# How can I get an ArraySegment<T> from a Span<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am trying to update an *API* to take advantage of `System.Memory.Span<T>` available [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/).

It seems the *API* for `MemoryStream` has not been updated to accept a `Span<T>` yet so I am wondering if I can convert the `Span<T>` to an `ArraySegment<T>` and use the stream as:

`memoryStream.Write(arraySeg.Array, arraySeg.Offset, arraySeg.Count);`

Any ideas?

Comment: Short of waiting for netstandard 2.1, it's going to be tricky. I don't know any way of casting a `Span` to an `Array` (`ArraySegment` is just adding one more step), and `MemoryStream` doesn't have any unsafe overload to use pointers. In some cases you could extract the buffer from the `MemoryStream` and directly do the copy, but it's not always possible (depending on what constructor you used for the stream). If everything else fails, you can still do this: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/8ec9bdfd53220b555f0b19eebd6a2c4ab5dab8bf/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L785

Comment: Excellent, I can use the pool to do that for the time being. Thank you!

Comment: Span-based overloads got added to MemoryStream in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22388
I.e. in .netcoreapp2.1 they are available.

If your API has to target other version (like netstandard2.0) then you can use multi-targeting to take advantage of the new features.